# I need to change the placeholder's text for certain situation(An If Statement like)

Tags: html, json, angular

I have text input and currently it's placeholder = enter 4 digits.

And lets assume I have a bool variable named "test" .

I'm trying to do => If test=true placeholder= enter 6 digits

else test= false placeholder = enter 4 digits

Actually the if condition is not based on a bool variable but if I understand this. I can work it for original problem.

```
<div class="left small-8 columns">
  <input 
    class="form-control" 
    id="vm_pin"
    whole-number
    maxlength="15"
    data-ng-readonly="is_restricted_user"
    data-ng-model="subscriber.vm_pin" 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="{{'6_digits' | xlat}}"                                                      
    tooltip="{{'vm_pin' | xlat_tooltip}}" 
  />
</div>
```

In related .json file

"4_digits":"4-15"

"6_digits":"6-15"

Comment: Are you reading some data from this json file and then determining what to display?

Comment: Yes its like that , {'6_digits' | xlat} it looks the related json file for "6_digits" and put it into placeholder

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
What you could do is use `[placeholder]="placeholder"` and apply the test in your component.

In your component:

```
get placeholder(){
 //YOUR TEST
 // test = your logic.
 return test ? 'Enter 6 digits': 'Enter 4 digits'
}
```

**Solution 2**

Directly in your template:

```
<div class="left small-8 columns">
  <input
    class="form-control" 
    id="vm_pin"
    whole-number
    maxlength="15"
    data-ng-readonly="is_restricted_user"
    data-ng-model="subscriber.vm_pin" 
    type="text" 
    [placeholder]="test ? 'Enter 4 digit' : 'Enter 6 digit')"                                                      
    tooltip="{{'vm_pin' | xlat_tooltip}}" 
  />
</div>
```

and in your component:

```
test(){
  // your logic to return the wanted result
}
```

*note: Prefer `[placeholder]="variable"` from `placeholder="{{variable}}"`*

Comment: note that text is getted from file so you can't bind prop, because you can't use interpolation with it

Comment: can't you `import * as data from './file.json';` in your component? And then use the variable `data` to output what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<input class="form-control" 
       id="vm_pin" 
       whole-number maxlength="15" 
       data-ng-readonly="is_restricted_user" 
       data-ng-model="subscriber.vm_pin" 
       type="text" 
       ng-attr-placeholder="{{test && '6_digits' || '4_digits' | xlat}}"
       tooltip="{{'vm_pin' | xlat_tooltip}}"
/>
```

Comment: It makes sense but where should I write my test function?

Comment: A.Sky, in component.ts file class in same place where you have bool variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="form-control" id="vm_pin" whole-number maxlength="15" data-ng-readonly="is_restricted_user" data-ng-model="subscriber.vm_pin" type="text" [placeholder]="check_condition ? '6-15 digits' : '4-15 digits')"
                                                             tooltip="{{'vm_pin' | xlat_tooltip}}" />
```

And in my js file I wrote this function below

```
function check_condition(){

    if(currentLocation.includes("172")){
        return true;  //or should I use [return '4-15 digits']
    }
    else
        return false;

}
```

But I couldn't see any placeholder

Answer (score 0):

I add this in the related js file

```
$scope.min_vm_pin_choice = $filter("xlat")(decide_min_vm_pin_for_placeholder());
```

And changed the html side like this

```
placeholder="{{min_vm_pin_choice}}"
```

And I wrote a function to change min_vm_pin value, and it works perfectly
Thanks for the ideas